# Fine-tune huggingface transformer to classify synonyms

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

I have a dataset of synonyms and non-synonyms. These are stored in a list of python dictionaries like `{"sentence1": <string>, "sentence2": <string>, "label": <1.0 or 0.0> }`. Note that this words (or sentences) do not have to be a single token in the tokenizer.

I want to fine-tune a BERT-based model to take both sentences like: `[[CLS], <sentence1_token1>, ...,<sentence1_tokenN>, [SEP], <sentence2_token1>, ..., <sentence2_tokenM>, [SEP]]`. I want to take the embedding for the `[CLS]` token (or the `pooled_ouput` available in some models) and run it through one or more perceptron layers (MLP).

Once I have this new model with the additional layers I want to train it using my data. I have found some examples and I have been able to create the desired pipeline (using PyTorch's `torch.nn` for the perceptron layers, although I am open to hear recommendations on what is best).

```
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(modelname)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(modelname)

# input_sentences1 is a list of the first sentence of every pair
# input_sentences2 is a list of the second sentence of every pair
input = tokenizer(  input_sentences1,
                    input_sentences2,
                    add_special_tokens = True,
                    padding=True,
                    return_tensors="pt" )

bert_output = model(**input)

# Extract embedding that will go through additional layers
pooled_output = bert_output.pooler_output
pooled_ouput_CLS_embedding =  pooled_output[:]
## OR
# sequence_output = bert_output.last_hidden_state
# sequence_ouput_CLS_embedding = sequence_output[:,0,:]

# First layer
linear1 = nn.Linear(768, 256)
linear1_output = linear1(pooled_ouput_CLS_embedding)

# Second layer
linear2 = nn.Linear(256, 1)
linear2_output = linear2(linear1_output)

linear2_output # Random results becuase the layers have not been trained
```

**How do I encapsulate this to facilitate training and how do I perform the fine tuning?**

Comment: It seems you want to ask multiple questions. It's often better to ask them in separate Q&As on SO.

Comment: @Trilarion Ok, should I edit the question to only ask 1 thing related to the title and make other questions about the other? Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is the desired way. Please keep in mind that different subquestions might require adjusted context, i.e., it won't be necessary to copy + paste the full information into each question, as only parts are relevant for it.